# Почему вместо строки отображается набор символов? А также почему не работает strcpy_s?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

Почему вместо строки выводится какой-то набор символов? И почему для аргументов ps и str функция strcpy_s не работает? (Выдаёт ошибку: отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "strcpy_s", соответствующие списку аргументов). Какую библиотечную функцию вместо strcpy_s тогда применять?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
void copy_str(char *str1, char* str2) {
    str1 = str2;
}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    char str[] = { 'H', 'i', '\0' };
    char *ps = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    copy_str(ps, str);
    //strcpy_s(ps, str); ошибка
    cout << "*ps = " << ps << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ваша функция `copy_str` ничего не делает. Копирование значения одного локального указателя в другой никак не влияет на "внешний мир".
2. Для использования функции `strcpy_s` надо включать заголовок `<cstring>`.
3. У функции `strcpy_s` *три* параметра, а не два. Два параметра можно указывать только тогда, когда первый параметр является массивом

   ```
   size_t dst_size = strlen(str) + 1;
   char *ps = new char[dst_size];
   strcpy_s(ps, dst_size, str);
   ```

Comment: 2, 3 пункт я понял. 1-ый не совсем. Допустим ест функция
void tolow(char *str1) {
 for (int i = 0; str1[i]; i++) {
  if (isupper(str1[i])) str1[i] = tolower(str1[i]);
 }
}

Comment: Она будет изменять значение строки вне функции, т.к. она была передана по адресу. Почему тогда копирования одного указателя в другой ничего не делает?

Comment: Как это можно объяснить? Я не понимаю почему так

Comment: @JustLearn: Когда вы модифицируете данные *на которые указывает указатель*, как в вашем примере с `str[i]`, это будет приводить к изменению строки "вне функции". Когда же вы просто меняете *сам указатель* (который является локальной переменной в функции), это разумеется ни на что влиять не будет. Ваше `copyt_str` вообще никак не обращается к строке.